# Category theory in plain MLTT

Tags: type-theory, ct.category-theory, homotopy-type-theory

I want to define a category in simple MLTT (not in HoTT). I defined it with the help of setoids. I.e. category consists of:

- a type of objects with equivalence relation (Obj : Set)
- a type of arrows between two objects with equivalence relation on it (Hom : Obj -> Obj -> Set)
- a set of category operations (i.e. id : (O : Obj) -> Hom O O, and composition)
- a proof that these operations respect equivalence relations

I defined simple notions of category theory with such a definitions, i.e. terminal objects, functors and I feel that everything looks fine.

However, I feel that definitions like this isn't exactly what we want when we talk about a category. Consider objects A, B, A' and B'. Assume A is equivalent to A' and B is equivalent to B'. We assume that the structure of arrows between A and B is in some sense isomorphic to A' and B' but the foregoing definition doesn't say anything about this. As far as I understand, HoTT, would require these types of arrows to be "equivalent".

What's wrong with this? What should be added? Is there any name for such a structure?

Comment: One option would be to simply omit the equivalence relation on Obj.  With the rest of the structure you can define what it means for two objects to be isomorphic; use that as the notion of equivalence for objects.

Comment: @MikeShulman But how can I do this? The only things that comes to my mind is to add "identity" arrows between equivalent objects.

Comment: I posted the same question to HoTT Cafe and got an interesting replies: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hott-cafe/RWcbIWiClNA However, I don't understand them so well that I will write an answer myself.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "how can I do this?"  *Omitting* something is easy, you just don't write it down.  (-:

Comment: Does http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.1364.pdf answer your question?

Comment: @Kai Yes, this article is exactly what I wanted.